# Can a Cordova Windows Phone 8.1 App Resume without restarting my web app?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, restart, visual-studio-cordova, resume

After opening and using my Windows Phone 8.1 Cordova App, I press the Windows key to go to my tile screen and then click on my App icon to bring it back.

On Resuming the last screen is breifley shown before restarting the App from index.html

During this restart I get a Flash of Unstyled Content from JQuery mobile widgets (that is usually hidden by the splash screen) before the app loads and I'm routed to the appropriate landing page.

Does anyone know of a way to prevent this app restart from happening?

Ideally I want the user to simply see the last screen they were on without the restart OR if the app has been terminated then I'd like the app to restart in the usual way without showing the user the last used screen first - like it does on iOS and Android

I'm developing using VS 2015 Enterprise RC

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it on an android device ?

Comment: Android and iOS working as expected. The issues only occurs on Windows (8.1) Phones. Incidently I receive this issue specifically on Nokia Lumia 920. On a Lumia 830 the app crashes out on Resume

Comment: Are you using `windows universal` or `wp8` accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Add ActivationPolicy="Resume" to DefaultTask in VMAppManifest.xml

```html
<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" ActivationPolicy="Resume" />
```

Comment: In my windows phone 8.1 cordova project, there is `package.appmanifest` so where to put this?